# Optimization of ListView with Asynctask for Smoother Scroll

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-scroll

I am working on a music application and a novice in android applications. I am using `ListView` to show content which is music files in the device. Here is what I am doing in the `ListView`:

1. Showing music file title, artist and duration
2. Album art of music file if available

**So**

The first point of what I am doing is easy to do and quite efficient with really smooth scroll behaviour, problem starts from second point i.e. loading album art of music file which I am doing with `AsyncTask`. I get `AsyncTask` working but it's **not the smartest `AsyncTask`**. For instance I want these two behaviours from my `ListView` and `AsyncTask`:

1. Start doing `AsyncTask` only when user stops scrolling - I want to save important CPU cycles when user tries to fling through views (scrolls fastly all across). Right now with my approach, when fling occurs all `AsyncTask` starts loading right away. I have implemented function `cancelPotentialTask()` and it cancels the task right away if I dont need it but what if I can control starting the task then that would be more efficient than cancelling it. Like when user stop scrolling `ListView` I get a trigger to start `AsyncTask`.
2. If `AsyncTask` once return result that no album art is available then it do not need to get into the task again if I call it again - This can be easily understood by picture below (sorry for poor editing).
   [image]

In first part, I let views to load up along with AsyncTask. In next one, I swipe up and get another view and let one row go to recycler. Third time I swipe down I get the recycled view back but Asynctask loads up but I do not need AsyncTask as it is really obvious result will be null as it was first time. I know code do not know this till we do not tell it. But how can I tell. I have a clue in `getView()` where I see if `convertView == null`.

Thanks for reading so far, I appreciate your patience. Here is the cheese for you -

```
   public Bitmap getAlbumart(Long album_id) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri
                    .parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);

            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = activity.getContentResolver()
                    .openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

            if (pfd != null) {
                FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd);
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        return bm;
    }

    // This is what I call to get image in getView()
    public void loadBitmap(String resId, ImageView imageView) {
        if (cancelPotentialWork(resId, imageView)) {
            String imageKey = String.valueOf(resId);
            LoadRows task = new LoadRows(imageView);
            SoftReference<Bitmap> bitmap1;
            try {
                bitmap1 = new SoftReference<>(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(getBitmapFromMemCache(imageKey), 80, 80, true));
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1.get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                SoftReference<AsyncDrawable> asyncDrawable = new SoftReference<>(new AsyncDrawable(resId, null,
                        task));
                imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable.get());
                task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, resId);
            }
        }
    }

    public class LoadRows extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        String data = null;
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        public LoadRows(ImageView imageView) {
            // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage
            // collected
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            data = params[0];

            Bitmap imageResult;
            imageResult = getAlbumart(Long.parseLong(data));

            if (imageResult != null) {
                imageResult = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageResult, 300, 300, true);
                addBitmapToMemoryCache(data, imageResult);
                imageResult = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageResult, 80, 80, true);
            }
            return imageResult;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);

            if (isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
            }

            if (bitmap != null) {
                ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                LoadRows bitmapWorkerTask = getLoadRows(imageView);
                if (this == bitmapWorkerTask) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }

        }

    }



    static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
        private final WeakReference<LoadRows> LoadRowsReference;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public AsyncDrawable(String res, Bitmap bitmap, LoadRows LoadRows) {
            super(bitmap);
            LoadRowsReference = new WeakReference<LoadRows>(LoadRows);
        }

        public LoadRows getLoadRows() {
            return LoadRowsReference.get();
        }
    }

    public static boolean cancelPotentialWork(String data, ImageView imageView) {
        final LoadRows LoadRows = getLoadRows(imageView);

        if (LoadRows != null) {
            final String bitmapData = LoadRows.data;
            // If bitmapData is not yet set or it differs from the new data
            if (bitmapData == "0" || bitmapData != data) {
                // Cancel previous task
                LoadRows.cancel(true);
            } else {
                // The same work is already in progress
                return false;
            }
        }
        // No task associated with the ImageView, or an existing task was
        // cancelled
        return true;
    }

    private static LoadRows getLoadRows(ImageView imageView) {
        if (imageView != null) {
            final Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
            if (drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
                final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = (AsyncDrawable) drawable;
                return asyncDrawable.getLoadRows();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Please guys take your time, I have no hurry to accept any answer really soon. Hope someone can play with code or if nothing but explain me what should be my approach.

If you guys need anything else to know, just let me know. Thank you!

**Edit**

getView() method -

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.text1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.duration = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textTime);
            holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.btn = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.button1);

            /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }


        if (data.size() > 0) {

            /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
            tempValues = null;
            tempValues = (ListModel) data.get(position);
            final String duration = tempValues.getDuration();
            final String artist = tempValues.getArtist();
            final String songName = tempValues.getName();
            final String title = tempValues.getTitle();
            final String albumid = tempValues.getAlbumID();

            String finalTitle;
            if (title != null) {
                finalTitle = title;
            } else {
                finalTitle = songName;
            }
            loadBitmap(albumid, holder.image); // HERE I GET IMAGE ***********

            holder.text.setText(finalTitle);
            holder.text1.setText(artist);
            holder.duration.setText(duration);

            vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MusicUtils.play(position, listModelToArrayList(), activity, songsManager);
                }
            });
            final PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(activity, holder.btn);
            int[] j = new int[6];
            j[0] = MusicUtils.PLAY;
            j[1] = MusicUtils.PLAY_NEXT;
            j[2] = MusicUtils.ADD_TO_QUEUE;
            j[3] = MusicUtils.ADD_TO_PLAYLIST;
            j[4] = MusicUtils.SHUFFLE_PLAY;
            j[5] = MusicUtils.DELETE;
            MusicUtils.generateMenu(pop, j);
            pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case MusicUtils.PLAY:
                            MusicUtils.play(position, listModelToArrayList(), activity, songsManager);
                            return true;
                        case MusicUtils.DELETE:
                            return true;
                        case MusicUtils.PLAY_NEXT:
                            MusicUtils.playNext(listModelToArrayList().get(position));
                            return true;
                        case MusicUtils.ADD_TO_QUEUE:
                            MusicUtils.addToQueue(listModelToArrayList().get(position), songsManager);
                            return true;
                        case MusicUtils.ADD_TO_PLAYLIST:
                            MusicUtils.addToPlaylist(position, listModelToArrayList().get(position), activity, songsManager);
                            return true;
                        case MusicUtils.SHUFFLE_PLAY:
                            MusicUtils.shufflePlay(position, listModelToArrayList(), activity, songsManager);
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            });


            holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pop.show();
                }
            });

            tempValues = null;
            vi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            vi.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return vi;
    }
```

**Update**

With using `UIL`, the result is almost same as the code I provided up i.e. laggy. But `Picasso` is really worth trying I would say the lag is almost gone. This is almost what I was looking to implement.

Comment: why you don't use library for loading image? like UIL (Universal Image Loader) or Picasso or ....?

Comment: I am not sure but those works for downloading images only maybe. If it can work then how can I do it with album arts of music files?

Comment: I tried UIL and there is no difference. Lag is still is same. Please help.

Comment: Did you get this code from http://developer.android.com ? I'm using the same code with modification and it works. Could you post how you're actually calling loadBitmap()?

Comment: Yes, I get this from Google Developers and did little modifications for supoorting `URI` of music files. I called it just below `if-else` check of `convertView`.

Comment: if you had problem for loading image with UIL , so problem is some where else, please comment code of loading image and check scrolling, if it's ok without image please post `getView` method

Comment: I have added `getView()` method in the post. @shayan

Comment: all thing seems to good, how you use UIL ( if your problem not solved yet as you mention that picasso solved your problem )

Comment: Yes @shayan I assume problem to be solved. Thank you for precious recommendation. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laggy scroll is gone with usage of library `Picasso`. I am still not sure what can be exact reason for this but just replacing my AsyncTask with Picasso works like charm. It is much more smoother and efficient as caching is done by library itself.

Here is the library https://github.com/square/picasso.